# Getting xdebug to talk to netbeans (from a virtual box)

Tags: netbeans, xdebug, vagrant

Trying to get xdebug to talk to netbeans (and vice versa).

xdebug is in a virtualbox setup with [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com/) (and some basic puppet to setup a basic LAMP). According to the php.ini from the VM everything is setup as I indented.

```
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=33.33.33.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

Unfortunately netbeans debugger just doesn't seem to be able to talk with xdebug.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. check wheather xdb is installed on vm using phpinfo()
2. Xdebug.remote_host should be vm ip address

Once everything is fine, You can use "Xdebug helper" chrome extention or "easy xdebug" firefox extention to open page in debug mode

Comment: What's xdb? Is it this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdb/ ?

Comment: Xdebug is php debugger, [xdebug website](http://xdebug.org/)